# java SE 6 implementation of int[] sort

Tags: java, sorting, implementation, quicksort, java-6

My friends told me that there are some error in the implementation of JavaSE6 sorting algorithm for int[], which is quicksort, I want to check the implementation, how can I do that? Where can I find the code?

Comment: You might not want to take programming advice from your friends.

Comment: ask your friend for the code.

Comment: The source is in the JDK and your IDE should load it automatically.  In my IDE, I can use `<ctrl>+<click>` on a method to see its source.

Comment: To down voting person: What's wrong with careful checking?

Comment: ctrl+click only shows me the .Class file, I found medium of 3 is used. "invokestatic java.util.Arrays.med3(int[], int, int, int) : int [445]"

Comment: To curious soul: google median-of-3 killer

Answer (score 1):

http://download.java.net/jdk6/source/

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this one:

http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html

It was a general problem, that a crucial calculation was prone to integer overflow.  Apparently your friends got it wrong.

Comment: It's the problem of "median of 3"

Comment: @safarisoul no, it is the problem of averaging two limited representation integers.

Comment: http://www.codeforces.com/blog/entry/4047

Comment: @safarisoul, yes, QuickSort has an O(n^2) worst case. That is not a _bug_.  Your point?

Comment: I don't care how you name it, bug or flower. And I know the worst case is rare, not likely to happen in real world. I'm just curious to the reason underneath. And thanks for the link you shared, a good point too.

Comment: @safarisoul you asked for an error in the implementation of quicksort which the incorrect calculation of the average of two integers is as it cause an exception.  Calculating the pivot element as the median of three elements instead of just picking the highest one (as in the original implementation of QuickSort) is not an error - it just causes the worst case to go from O(n log n) to O(n^2).  Vast difference.